# boost python with anaconda in visual studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, anaconda, boost-python

I have boost installed with visual studio 2015, the boost libraries had been running fine in my visual studio, until I started trying out boost python. I have anaconda installed in `c:\Anaconda2`, and `c:\Anaconda2` is in my `PATH` variable. But even a simple program couldn't run.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "0 -----" << std::endl;
  Py_Initialize();
  std::cout << "1 -----" << std::endl;
}
```

The code outputs "0 -----" and gives an error:

> Import Error: No module named site

which suggests the initialization doesn't make through.

I suspect this is due to some environment variable/path issue, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work. Can somebody please help?

Comment: I think the Anaconda may have eaten the Python.

Comment: @rasmeister, what do you mean? I dont think you are fully joking.

Comment: Actually, yes I was fully joking. Sorry, couldn't resist!

Comment: @Allanqunzi did you ever fix the issue?  I'm having similar trouble; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552092/boost-python-embedding-error