# Boost Python Embedding Error

Tags: c++, python-3.x, anaconda, boost-python, python-embedding

I've just built [Boost Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) on Windows 10 with an  [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) version of Python 3.5 (64 bit).  I used these [instructions](http://www.sigverse.org/wiki/en/index.php?Compiling%20Boost.Python%20for%20Python%20in%20Visual%20Studio) modified to my suit my installation and have successfully built the testCode.cpp using Visual Studio 2015:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>  
using namespace boost::python;  

int main()  
{  
    try {  
        Py_Initialize();  

        object main_module((  
            handle<>(borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("__main__")))));  

        object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");  

        handle<> ignored(( PyRun_String( "print (\"Hello, World\")",  
            Py_file_input,  
            main_namespace.ptr(),  
            main_namespace.ptr() ) ));  
    } catch( error_already_set ) {  
        PyErr_Print();  
    }  
}
```

However when I run the application I get these errors:

```
C:\Users\Stephen\Source\Repos\TestPythonEmbedding\x64\Release>TestPythonEmbedding
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Stephen\Anaconda3\Lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
import os
File "C:\Users\Stephen\Anaconda3\Lib\os.py", line 652, in <module>
from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
File "C:\Users\Stephen\Anaconda3\Lib\_collections_abc.py", line 64
async def _ag(): yield
                ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' inside async function
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here and how to fix it?

Thanks